# (Python3.4) tkinter messagebox not work when it executed by cx_freeze

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, cx-freeze

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os','tkinter','random',
                              'heapq','collections','sys','pickle']}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = 'Game',
        version = '0.02',
        description = 'My GUI application!',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('Game.py', base=base)])
```

here's the code of the setup

```
from tkinter import *
value_a = 'hahaha'
a =messagebox.showinfo('laugh',value_a)
```

and the code that would executed

the erorr is `Nameerorr : name "messagebox" is not defined` when I typed `python 123.py build` or `python haha.py build` in cmd

I already used `import *`, if I run the code it shows message but neither in cmd nor .exe

Should I use `import tkinter as tk`? But it is difficult to read my code by adding "tk", I want to keep `import *` so that no "tk.xxx" is needed and it will still works on exe.

Comment: Which version of `Python` are you using?

Comment: That Game.py doesn't seem to work when executed due to missing `import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox`

Comment: `But it is difficult to read my code by adding "tk"`..Actually adding`tk` _improves_ readability because it tells reader from where that name came but of course this not your main problem here.

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`from tkinter import *` does not work for *messagebox*, so you must import the message box individually like below

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  It worked OK in the IDE but not in direct run mode.
Adding `import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox` fixed the problem.
Thanks, G.